# how to deal with multiple configurations in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, configuration

I've an application made of JScript/html pages and I would like to make them configurable according to various options. 
For instance, one of these options is the current language which may modify the layout (I'm dealing with language variation) of the page (i'm working on an ERP and according to the country different rules may apply).

I'm a newbie in this kind of technology and what I was thinking about is something like the way configuration options are dealt with in the linux kernel. Basically, I would define macros (cpp macros) which are expanded differently according to the current language. Doing so, the package delivered only contains the pages for one country while my codebase centralizes everything. I don't know if this is the right way to do it, if there's any.

hope this is clear enough..

Answer (score 0):

The question is fairly generic so it's hard to give a good answer. There are no macros in js (unless you use some preprocessor). But the dynamic nature of js lets you redefine variables, functions, etc on the fly. You could perhaps have a file for each country and just include that, letting it plug in the holes in your code?

Comment: ok, fair enough...how do you conditionally include file in JS ? and how is it possible to make the html layout vary according to a configuration property (for lack of a better name)...

Comment: It sounds more and more like you would benefit from a preprocessor.

Includes can be done by using `document.write()` to insert HTML before the page has finished loading (kind of ugly), or by waiting until the page has loaded and using `document.createElement` and `document.appendChild`. For the layout, add css files in a similar fashion, or print html with `document.write` or by using DOM manipulation.

Any time you end up with `document.write` you are probably better off with a preprocessor.

Comment: yep, that's exactly what i think. I'd have liked something more elegant than using the old cpp...